# Realization of active buttons in listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My button "delete" doesnt work
I use MVVM(CaliburnMicro).

How I can realize work buttons in listbox?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listContactDatas}" Margin="36,38,78,131">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <Button                                
                x:Name="delete">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: can you explain the "isn't active"?

Comment: @sexta13, it doesnt work

Comment: It should have some kind of Command no? In MvvmLight you have to have something like <Button Command ={Binding CommandXPTO} /> and in your ViewModel have the public RelayCommand CommandXPTO{get;private set;}
In Caliburn must be something similar too....

Comment: take a look at this: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions
It explains very well the use of commands for Caliburn framework!

Comment: Put `ClickMode="Press"` on your Button

Comment: Add some content. Bind it to a command or add a event handler for click event.